# Multiple users can't access server's shared drive under NAT

Tags: windows, nat, netbios

The setup is

```
Server
-computer
-computer
Router
    -computer
    -computer
    -computer
    -computer
```

If multiple computers underneath the router try to access the drive at the same time, it says the network name can't be found.

Comment: tell us more detail please. router vendor? how is it configured. Server OS ? do you have server/router logs? Access from to would be very helpful

Comment: Server OS is Win Server 2003 R2 x64, client is winxp pro x86. It's a linksys E1000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you disable direct hosting, sharing files over NAT will work.

Start Registry Editor.
Locate and then click the following registry key:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\NetBT\Parameters
Add the following registry value:
Value Name: SmbDeviceEnabled
Type: REG_DWORD
Value Data: 0

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to try to answer your question even though the setup is not very clear.
There are two assumption that are going to be made in my answer and these assumption are that the computers between the "Router" are using different NAT's and that there is some kind of firewall or access-control mechanism.

If that is the case, then you will need to allow the following ports or route these ports between computers behind the "Router" and the "Server".

The ports are:

- TCP ports 135-to-139
- UDP ports 135-to-139
- TCP port 445

In addition to that, do the following:

1. Open the Network Adapter "Properties"
2. "Advanced TCP/IP Settings"
3. Choose the "WINS" tab
4. Make sure the NetBIOS is in "Default" or "Enabled"

I hope this helps you out.

Comment: I will check all of this on Wednesday.

Comment: I checked it all, but anytime two people access the server at the same time it's still saying network name can't be found, also, if I'm in the middle of a file transfer and someone accesses it, the error pops up, which seems weird, seeing as it's already got the ip. Even if I connect by \\ip_address_here I still get the error.

Comment: @MMavipc when this happen, which transfer receives the error ? The ongoing one or the new one ? Maybe double check the configuration of the fileshare to make sure you didn't limit the concurrent sessions. You can see that in the Advanced properties on the share. Also, please check then EventViewer on both client computers and on the Server. Maybe we'll find something there.

Comment: the ongoing one receives the error, don't have access to the computer right now, but I will check it later

Comment: on all of the shares the # of connections have their limit set to "Maximum Allowed"